# Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 accessing TFS 2008 source control?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2005

We have a TFS 2008 server that we are using for source control having migrated away from VSS  :D  This is great for all our web projects as they can all be migrated to VS2008.

My problem is that VS2008 doesn't support development of SQL2005 SSIS packages.

It is possible to check SSIS packages into TFS2008 from VS2005?  Would this conflict with the VS2008 install on the same workstation?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'll be fine if you install Team Explorer 2005 onto Visual Studio 2005.

> Out of the box, Team Explorer 2005 works very well with most of the TFS 2008 capabilities.  Work Item Tracking and Version Control function the same as they always had for TFS 2005.  End users wouldn't even notice the difference, except in some rare cases the increased performance.

From : http://weblogs.asp.net/dmckinstry/archive/2007/08/27/considerations-on-using-tfs-2008-with-visual-studio-2005.aspx